# How do you get an image from a "t.co" URL (Twitter specific images) for an iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

normally if you want an image from a URL there are plenty of ways to do it from a standard URL like this one:

a)
https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CFDqQYMWYAAB_R8.png:large

However, if you extract a Twitter feed into an iOS app, you get the text and "t.co" URL from the string, which looks like this:

b) http://t.co/aQ7Q9eavlO

Now Xcode can't grab an image from that URL, but it stands to reason that there should be a way to go deeper, and get the image in link "b" so that it opens it to the format of link "a" so that I can show the image referenced in the tweet in my app, and not an unusable URL that returns a blank screen instead of the image in my imageView

As per request, I have updated the question to include the process I am using to get the images from the URL links:

// I won't add the whole Twitter/Social application, just the highlights

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                            [self.tableView reloadData];

NSDictionary *tweet = _array[indexPath.row];

tweetLabel.text = tweet[@"text"];

// I use "NSRegularExpression" To extract JUST the url from the tweet

// t.co address you get from the twitter feed

NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://t.co/aQ7Q9eavlO"];

// manually going to the page and getting the image URL

NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CFDqQYMWYAAB_R8.png:large"];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL : url]; // url1 gives nothing/ url2 gives the actual image

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];

tempView.ContentView.image = image;

Both links come from the same place, but one uses the Twitter API to get the URL Twitter wants to share, the other gets the actual file URL. I can't find anyway to programmatically do the same thing, with usual XCode methods or using the Twitter/social frameworks

Comment: Xcode has nothing to do with getting a URL. Update your question with the code you use to load the image from the URL. There is no reason why you can't use link "b" if your code is correct.

Comment: You should format your code with the code tag to make it readable

Comment: Use an `NSURLConnection` so you properly handle the redirects.

Comment: I'll look into "NSURLConnection" thank you

Answer (score 0):

The URL you're trying to download is not the image, it's just a link to a page for the tweet containing it.

Using this command:

```
curl -L -v http://t.co/aQ7Q9eavlO
```

You can see it's just plain HTML.

Comment: Yes, I realised that because it's not an image but a page, I was hoping that there was a way to show just the image. Thank you for you're reply but I'm sorry because I don't know how to use the command : "curl -L -v http://t.co/aQ7Q9eavlO" Is the curl something I need to do in Xcode or is it to do with the URL, like a means of editing it? Forgive me if my ignorance is burdening